# Cant Solve This SQL Error

Tags: php, mysql

i have an insert statement in which i am getting the following error message:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ref = '6u5i14e'' at line 1
```

this is my php file:

```
    <?php

$secret_question = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['secret_question']);
$secret_anwser = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['secret_anwser']);


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","*****","*****");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('*****', $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO public (secret_question, secret_anwser) VALUES ('$secret_question','$secret_answer') WHERE ref = '". $_SESSION['ref']."' ";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else 
  {
      echo '<hr><h3>Your Account Has Now Been Activated. <br/> <a href = "votenow.php">Please Login To Vote</a></h3><hr>';

  }
?>
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: INSERT...WHERE isn't valid SQL syntax, is it? :)

Comment: By the way, you use `$secret_anwser` at the beginning and then `$secret_answer` in the query.

Comment: Make sure you also `mysql_real_escape_string()` the session value. Storing the value in the session does *not* escape it

Comment: Seems like a job for `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`...

Comment: Please do not forget to accept the appropriate response.

Answer (score 3):

Check your spelling of 'answer'. You're spelling it differently in different places in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an update not an insert.

```
$sql="UPDATE public SET 
   secret_question='$secret_question', secret_anwser='$secret_answer' 
   WHERE ref = '". $_SESSION['ref']."' ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use UPDATE instead of INSERT in case you want to modify existing data.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT...VALUES does not take a WHERE. If you need to run a WHERE statement, then you will need to do it like below. However, this seems like it should be an update and not an insert, so be careful

```
INSERT INTO public (secret_question, secret_anwser) 
SELECT '$secret_question','$secret_answer'
FROM public
WHERE ref = '". $_SESSION['ref']."' "
```

Suggested query:

```
UPDATE public
SET secret_question = '$secret_question', 
    secret_anwser = '$secret_answer'
WHERE ref = '". $_SESSION['ref']."' "
```